# How to determine font-weight bold without using getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm in the process of making an HTML text parser and I would like to be able to determine when a text node appears as a header (visually, not HTML headers).

One thing that can usually be said about headers are that they are emphasized - usually in one of two ways: Bold font or larger font size.

I could get both corresponding CSS values using `getComputedStyle()`, but I want to avoid this because the parser needs high performance (has to run smoothly on, for example, Chromebooks) and `getComputedStyle()` is not particularly fast when looking through hundreds or thousands of nodes.

Figuring out a font size isn't too hard - I can just select the node with `range` and check its client rects from `range.getClientRects()`.I haven't figured out a smart way to check font weight though, which is why I'm here.

**Can anyone think of higher-performance way of doing this than by using `getComputedStyle()`?**

I'm aware this might not be possible - just looking to see if someone can think of an ingenious way to solve this problem.

**Edit**

This is for a Google Chrome extension only.

Comment: What about putting it in bold and checking if there's a size difference ?

Comment: It's a good idea, but it's also much slower than `getComputedStyle()` according to a quick test I just did.

Answer (score 0):

What you're aiming to do here is really messy. Since you want to determine if text is bold visually, on some devices, depending on how they render text, the whole system may just break!

A suggestion I have is to use the HTML5 Data atrributes - find out more [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) - and use it like so:

```
<div class="header" data-bold="yes">This will appear bold?</div>
```

Then, using JavaScript you can just go over all div elements with the data-bold attribute.

I hope this helped ;)

Comment: I've added a little comment that this is for a Google Chrome extension only. Also I'm not serving the HTML, so I can't make any changes to it.